# UIbutton highlight part of the image

Tags: ios, uibutton, highlight

I want to have a UIButton that has an image as the button itself, to have a nice highlight when pressed but not on the entire rectangle but on the object in the image (quite similar to what Twitter is doing on the status bar buttons)

I thought that making an image with the background as transparent will solve the problem, the thing is that on one it works, and on one it doesn't and they are exactly the same property wise.

So my general question:
What are the steps I need to do in order to get this done?

Comment: Could you please give an example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: latest Twitter iOS app - the tweet/search icons on the status bar. Click and don't let go to see the effect I want to acheive

Comment: I tried to make a screen shot of the button that does work but I can't make a screenshot and click on the same time :(